# jquery .val() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

The relevant part of the code is shown below. When I click the Submit button, on the alert box, I get undefined, rather than the typed email. What mistake am I doing here?

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()" id="form1"> 
        ......
        <input type="text" name="YourEMail" style="width: 250px;"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        ......
</form> 

<script>
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    //your validation rules here
    var email = $('#YourEMail').val()
    alert(email)
    //if(email.length == 0)
        return false;
    //else 
    //  return true;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`YourEMail` is the `name`, not the `id`:

```
var email = $('input[name=YourEMail]').val();
```

Or change the `input` to have the `id`:

```
<input type="text" id="YourEMail" name="YourEMail" style="width: 250px;">
```

Comment: You just beat me to it.:)

Comment: or add to the tag <input type="text" *id="YourEMail"* name="YourEMail" style="width: 250px;">

Comment: Awesome. I din't know it was that easy :)!

Answer (score 2):

Check this working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3h4n6qfe/1/

You are calling a `id` and jQuery returning it as null as there is no `id` for your input field

Modify from:

```
<input type="text" name="YourEMail" style="width: 250px;">
```

To:

```
<input type="text" name="YourEMail" id="YourEMail" value="My Email" style="width: 250px;">
```

and you're good to go!

Comment: Use stack overflows code simulator instead of jsfiddle

Comment: @EdwardBlack many here uses `jsfiddle`, there is no problem with it. He can do how he like ...

Comment: And what are we doing if jsfiddle is offline? Why using an external code simulator if stackoverflow has its own?!

Comment: Well that could have different reasons. I personally like `jsfiddle` more too, because you have more space for the code, you can easily make test/changes there, has a full split for `html`, `css` and `js` and things like `ajax` or `libraries`. For small things you may use the `SO` solution, but for bigger, I would always prefer `jsfiddle` ... And: there is no rule to use the inline version! So, everyone can do how he wants to. :) @EdwardBlack

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was because different element types had same id.